# Attribute pairs via correlation over multiple tables

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataframe and am calculating correlations between columns to decide which attributes to remove. I'd like to create a table where the rows are the Attributes of my data-frame and next to each attribute there's a list of those which have correlations >= 0.65 or <= -0.65 with that attribute. The catch is I want to include only those attributes which have correlations of this magnitude, on TWO sets of correlation tests (one using `use="complete.obs"`, one using `use="pairwise.complete.obs"`).

An example:

```
set.seed(1234)
n=8
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n^2,min=0,max=1),nrow=n,ncol=n))
colnames(df) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(df)]

df$A[3] <- NA
df$C[2] <- NA
df$E[7] <- NA

cor1 <- cor(df, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
cor2 <- cor(df, use="complete.obs")
```

Here, you can form the relevant individual matrices as follows

```
cor1[-0.65<cor1 & cor1<0.65] <- NA
cor2[-0.65<cor2 & cor2<0.65] <- NA
```

At this point I want to know how to create a table of the attributes followed by (for each attribute) only those who have non-NA values for correlation in **both** the above two matrices `cor1` and `cor2`. So e.g. in this example, the desired output would be:

```
A:     G
B:     D, H
C:     E
D:     B, H
E:     C
F:
G:     A
H:     B, D
```

Note for example G is not listed for F, or F for G, because in `cor1` the correlation is -0.01899381, even though the correlation in `cor2` is -0.9186308346. BOTH correlations must be above 0.65 or below 0.65 to be included in the list.

Edit: an ideal method would take care of something I fail to above--the possibility that a correlation could be >0.65 in `cor1` and <-0.65 in `cor2` and get through, unlikely as this is. We'd prefer to list only those which are >=0.65 on *both matrices* or <=-0.65 on both matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to consider. Create a logical matrix where the absolute value of each correlation is greater than .65, and set diagonal to FALSE. Use `apply` and `paste` together the names of TRUE in the matrix, comma separated.

```
mat <- abs(cor1)>.65 & abs(cor2)>.65

diag(mat) <- F

as.matrix(apply(mat, 1, function(x) paste (names(which(x)), collapse = ",")))
```

**Output**

```
  [,1] 
A "G"  
B "D,H"
C "E"  
D "B,H"
E "C"  
F ""   
G "A"  
H "B,D"
```